# Prolog Extended Euclidian Algorithm

Tags: prolog

I have been struggling with some prolog code for several days and I couldn't find a way out of it. I am trying to write the extended Euclidean algorithm and find values `p` and `s` in :

```
a*p + b*s = gcd(a,b)
```

equation and here is what I have tried :`

```
 common(X,X,X,_,_,_,_,_,_).
 common(0,Y,Y,_,_,_,_,_,_).
 common(X,0,X,_,_,_,_,_,_).

 common(X,Y,_,1,0,L1,L2,SF,TF):-
                                  append(L1,1,[H]),
                                  append(L2,0,[A]),
                                  SF is H ,
                                  TF is A,
                                  common(X,Y,_,0,1,[H],[A],SF,TF).

 common(X,Y,_,0,1,L1,L2,SF,TF):-
                                  append(L1,0,[_,S2]),
                                  append(L2,1,[_,T2]),
                                  Q is truncate(X/Y),
                                  S is 1-Q*0,T is 0-Q*1 ,
                                  common(X,Y,_,S,T,[S2,S],
                                  [T2,T],SF,TF).

 common(X,Y,N,S,T,[S1,S2],[T1,T2],SF,TF):-
                                  Q is truncate(X/Y),
                                  K is X-(Y*Q),
                                  si_finder(S1,S2,Q,SF),
                                  ti_finder(T1,T2,Q,TF),

common(Y,K,N,S,T,[S2,S],[T2,T],SF,TF).


si_finder(PP,P,Q,C):- C is  PP - Q*P.

ti_finder(P2,P1,QA,C2):- C2 is P2 - QA*P1.
```

After a little search I found that s and p coefficients start from 1 and 0 and the second values for them are 0 and 1 respectively.Then it continues in a pattern which is what I have done in si_finder and ti_finder predicates.Common predicates are where I tried to control the pattern recursively. However the common predicates keeps on returning false in every call. Can anyone help me implement this algorithm in Prolog.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find [this video explaining the algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hB34-GSDT3k) helpful. I think your predicate has a lot more arguments than you really require.

Comment: Thank you ,I have watched this video while searching but this requires back-substitution as I am finding the coefficients that's  where I am stuck. I started implementing my code according to [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) and find the coefficients in that way

Comment: Your could use constraints. Have a look at the manual for the library clpfd.

Answer (score 3):

First let's think about the arity of the predicate. Obviously you want to have the numbers A and B as well as the Bézout coefficients P and S as arguments. Since the algorithm is calculating the GCD anyway, it is opportune to have that as an argument as well. That leaves us with arity 5. As we're talking about the extended Euclidean algorithm, let' call the predicate `eeuclid/5`. Next, consider an example: Let's use the algorithm to calculate P, S and GCD for A=242 and B=69:

```
quotient (Q) | remainder    (B1) |   P   |   S
-------------+-------------------+-------+-------
             |              242  |   1   |   0
             |              69   |   0   |   1
242/69 = 3   | 242 − 3*69 = 35   |   1   |  -3
69/35  = 1   | 69 − 1*35  = 34   |  -1   |   4
35/34  = 1   | 35 − 1*34  = 1    |   2   |  -7
34/1   = 34  | 34 − 34*1  = 0    | -69   | 242
```

We can observe the following:

- The algorithm stops if the remainder becomes 0
- The line before the last row contains the GCD in the remainder column (in this example 1) and the Bézout coefficients in the P and S columns respectively (in this example 2 and -7)
- The quotient is calculated from the previous to remainders. So in the next iteration A becomes B and B becomes B1.
- P and S are calculated from their respective predecessors. For example: P3 = P1 - 3*P2 = 1 - 3*0 = 1 and S3 = S1 - 3*S2 = 0 - 3*1 = -3. And since it's sufficient to have the previous two P's and S's, we might as well pass them on as pairs, e.g. P1-P2 and S1-S2.
- The algorithm starts with the pairs P: 1-0 and S: 0-1
- The algorithm starts with the bigger number

Putting all this together, the calling predicate has to ensure that A is the bigger number and, in addition to it's five arguments, it has to pass along the starting pairs 1-0 and 0-1 to the predicate describing the actual relation, here `a_b_p_s_/7`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

eeuclid(A,B,P,S,GCD) :-
   A #>= B,
   GCD #= A*P + B*S,                % <- new
   a_b_p_s_(A,B,P,S,1-0,0-1,GCD).
eeuclid(A,B,P,S,GCD) :-
   A #< B,
   GCD #= A*P + B*S,                % <- new
   a_b_p_s_(B,A,S,P,1-0,0-1,GCD).
```

The first rule of `a_b_p_s_/7` describes the base case, where B=0 and the algorithm stops. Then A is the GCD and P1, S1 are the Bézout coefficients. Otherwise the quotient Q, the remainder B1 and the new values for P and S are calculated and `a_b_p_s_/7` is called with those new values:

```
a_b_p_s_(A,0,P1,S1,P1-_P2,S1-_S2,A).
a_b_p_s_(A,B,P,S,P1-P2,S1-S2,GCD) :-
   B #> 0,
   A #> B,                          % <- new
   Q #= A/B,
   B1 #= A mod B,
   P3 #= P1-(Q*P2),
   S3 #= S1-(Q*S2),
   a_b_p_s_(B,B1,P,S,P2-P3,S2-S3,GCD).
```

Querying this with the above example yields the desired result:

```
?- eeuclid(242,69,P,S,GCD).
P = 2,
S = -7,
GCD = 1 ;
false.
```

And indeed: gcd(242,69) = 1 = 2*242 − 7*69

**EDIT:** On a second thought I would suggest to add two constraints. Firstly Bézout's identity before calling `a_b_p_s_/7` and secondly `A #> B` after the first goal of `a_b_p_s_/7`. I edited the predicates above and marked the new goals. These additions make `eeuclid/5` more versatile. For example, you could ask what numbers A and B have the Bézout coefficients 2 and -7 and 1 as the gcd. There is no unique answer to this query and Prolog will give you residual goals for every potential solution. However, you can ask for a limited range for A and B, say between 0 and 50 and then use `label/1` to get actual numbers:

```
?-  [A,B] ins 0..50, eeuclid(A,B,2,-7,1), label([A,B]).
A = 18,
B = 5 ;
A = 25,
B = 7 ;
A = 32,
B = 9 ;
A = 39,
B = 11 ;
A = 46,
B = 13 ;
false.       % <- previously loop here
```

Without the newly added constraints the query would not terminate after the fifth solution. However, with the new constraints Prolog is able to determine, that there are no more solutions between 0 and 50.